# List to array Netlogo

Tags: arrays, list, netlogo

My problem is about converting a block of list data to the array, however, I am stuck on this and have tried to code it in all possible ways that I can think of. Unfortunately, I could not figure it out.

First, I have two text files which contain these values:

> 0 1 2 3 438 418 424 434 439 417 421 0 ... 447 412 426 436 448 413 422
>   0

Then I want to add it to Netlogo so I use this:

```
extensions [table matrix array csv]
globals
[
  Dummy-Retrieve-list
  patch-data
  string-array
]
to setup
file-close-all
ca
file-open "Matching.txt"
while [ not file-at-end? ]
  [
    set string-array (list n-values 4 [file-read])
    print string-array
    let i 0
    foreach string-array
    [ x -> array:set patch-data i x
      set i (i + 1)
      print patch-data
    ]
  print patch-data
  ]
file-close
```

What I want here is to take a batch of 4 values (maybe n-values in the future) in the input list and then form it into an array as input for another array. However, I don't know how, so I use the `foreach` function to make loop through the values and then use `array:set` to set data onto the new array.

I don't know how the position of the values will change so I use the "set i (i + 1)" to preserve ordering. But it returns `false`, as it expects an anonymous command instead of list or block so I'm stuck.

Does anyone know any easier ways for transforming a list of values into a list of array values? The reason I ask this is that in the future, it may be not 4 values that will be selected but perhaps more of it, so it is impossible to use code like this:

```
set string-array list file-read file-read file-read file-read
```

That is why I use `list n-values 4 [file-read]` instead. I have also searched Google and all other examples provided by NetLogo program however still not figure it out.

In summary, what I want is transforming a list like this:

```
[[v11 v21 v31 ... vn1] [[v12 v22 v32 ... vn2] ... [v1m v2m v3m ... vnm]]
```

Into this array:

```
{{array: {{array: v11 v21 v31 ... vn1}} {{array: v12 v22 v32 ... vn2}} ... {{array: v1m v2m v3m ... vnm}}}}
```

Comment: Why do you need an array? Unless you have very unusual performance requirements, you should probably just stick to lists.

Comment: Dear Nicolas,the reason I need array is for strictly controlling the data then using the array for accessing/storing data exactly instead of lists,in which I found not so familiar with.In example,I want to make my agents move to various points A,B,...,N and at each points they will perform an action in there.In order to control the points they move,I will record it to an array and then hand-checking it to see if it moves as I expected.Moreover, because my lists change every loop hence I want an array for retrieving information and check it later so I record it to array instead of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way to answer my question and it is using the double `foreach` loop.

Thank you for helping me on the way answering it, @NicolasPayette.

This is the answer for my problem:

```
file-open "Matching.txt"
let k 0
while [ not file-at-end? ]
[
  let j 0
  set string-array (list n-values 4 [file-read])
  print string-array
  foreach string-array 
  [ [i] -> foreach i
    [ [m] -> insert-retrieval j k m
      set j j + 1
    ]
  ]
  set k k + 1
  print Retrieve-list
]
file-close
```

`insert-retrieval j k m` is a function for inputting data into the Retrieve-list with j is the column, k is the row and m is the value.